# Passing byte array; passes junit test, but cant call method regularly?

Tags: java, encryption, for-loop, error-handling, arrays

Working on a bit of encryption using des in java. I have a bunch of methods as well as some junit test cases. The method im having trouble with receives a byte array and an int and at that position (int) it flips the bit. so like using an 8 byte byte Array with 64 bits in total it receives the hex byte array [ ad 12 45 67 c3 65 3a 66 ] transforms it into a 64 bit long binary string and flips whatever position. This method passes the test cases in junit (which were given to me) but now im trying to do something else with the program but it wont let me call flip in general.

here is the code and the errors im getting. in the first for loop of flip people suggest i change the <= to just a < , but in doing that it then fails my junit tests.

My goal is to go through the given plaintext one bit at a time and flip it to observe the changes in the given ciphertext. thats what the diff method is used for ( to count the diff between the 2 byte arrays). This is all done in that small for loop in the main.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        //take original plain text and get the ct to compare all other ct's to
        String plaintxt = "Coolbro!";
        byte [] ptAr = getBytes(asciiToHex(plaintxt));
        byte [] ctFinal = encrypt(ptAr);
        byte [] ptCopy;
        byte [] newCt;
        int differences =0;

        for ( int j = 63; j >= 0; j--){

            ptCopy = flip(ptAr, 2);
            newCt = encrypt(ptCopy);
            differences = diff(ctFinal,newCt);
            System.out.println(differences);

        }


    }

    public static int diff( byte [] a, byte [] b){
    int diff = 0;
    String byteAr1;
    String byteAr2;
    char A1 [];
    char A2 [];

    byteAr1 = hexToBin(a);
    byteAr2 = hexToBin(b);

    A1 = byteAr1.toCharArray();
    A2 = byteAr2.toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++){
        if(A1[i] != A2[i]){
            diff++;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}

    public static byte [] flip(byte [] a, int position){

        byte[] copy = a;
        String temp = "";
        String tempf = "";
        for(int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){
            temp = temp + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(a[i])).replace(' ', '0');
        }
        if(temp.charAt(position) == '1'){
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
                if (i == position){
                    tempf += "0";
                }
                else{
                    tempf += temp.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
                if (i == position){
                    tempf += "1";
                }
                else{
                    tempf += temp.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
        temp = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(tempf, 2));
        byte [] fin = temp.getBytes();


        return fin;
```

and here are the errors that this produces for me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at AvalancheUtilities.flip(AvalancheUtilities.java:55)
at AvalancheUtilities.main(AvalancheUtilities.java:18)
```

and like i said above if i were to change the <= to just a < then i get these erros:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0110001101101111011011110110110001100010011100100110111100100001"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at AvalancheUtilities.flip(AvalancheUtilities.java:77)
at AvalancheUtilities.main(AvalancheUtilities.java:18)
```

I dont really know how to handle either case. Preferrably i would like to stick with the <= because it passes the test cases.

thanks for any help i know that was alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your "people" are correct, you want to change the <= to a <.  Looking at your exception, you only have 8 items in your array, which means you can only index from 0 to 7.  The last index will always be 1 less than the length of the array.

For the other exception, the problem is that your number is too large.  See [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

Switch it to:

```
temp = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(tempf, 2));
```

Comment: well it does work when i do that but that also doubles the length of my byte array. which then i cannot compare 2 things if one is length 8 and the other 16

Comment: You may want to check your logic, then.  The number you tried to parse is 64 bits, which is more than Integer can handle.  Are you sure you want tempf to be one long string, and not an array of 8-bit strings?